# Django Channel with Nginx Redirect

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-channels

I'm using django channel for my Django application. On top of Django, I add nginx as layer for http request. All http request is working nicely, but when I tried to create a websocket connection, it was getting 302 HTTP Code.

## Nginx Configuration

```
# Enable upgrading of connection (and websocket proxying) depending on the
# presence of the upgrade field in the client request header
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

# Define connection details for connecting to django running in
# a docker container.
upstream uwsgi {
    server uwsgi:8080;
}
server {
    # OTF gzip compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 860;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/json;
    gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8080;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    #server_name *;
    charset     utf-8;

    error_page 500 502 /500.html;

    location = /500.html {
        root /html;
        internal;
    }

    # max upload size, adjust to taste
    client_max_body_size 15M;
    # Django media
    location /media  {
        # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        alias /home/web/media;
        expires 21d; # cache for 71 days
    }
    location /static {
        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        alias /home/web/static;
        expires 21d; # cache for 21 days
    }
    location /archive {
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        autoindex on;
        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        alias /home/web/archive;
        expires 21d; # cache for 6h
    }
    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
        # the uwsgi_params file you installed needs to be passed with each
        # request.
        # the uwsgi_params need to be passed with each uwsgi request
        uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
        uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://uwsgi;
            break;
        }
        # Require http version 1.1 to allow for upgrade requests
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # We want proxy_buffering off for proxying to websockets.
        proxy_buffering off;
        # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # enable this if you use HTTPS:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        # pass the Host: header from the client for the sake of redirects
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # We've set the Host header, so we don't need Nginx to muddle
        # about with redirects
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Depending on the request value, set the Upgrade and
        # connection headers
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

## Routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route
from consumers import ws_add, ws_message, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_add),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]
```

## Consumers. py

```
from channels import Channel, Group
from channels.sessions import channel_session
from channels.auth import channel_session_user, channel_session_user_from_http


# Connected to websocket.connect
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_add(message):
    # Accept the connection
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the group
    Group("progress-%s" % message.user.username).add(message.reply_channel)


@channel_session_user
def ws_message(message):
    Group("progress-%s" % message.user.username).send({
        "text": message['text'],
    })


# Connected to websocket.disconnect
@channel_session_user
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("progress-%s" % message.user.username).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

If i remove the nginx layer it is working nicely. Is there any configuration that I miss?